# If else statement foreach loop

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

I have a foreach loop and I want to add an if else statement inside it...

It is driving me crazy so any help would be very welcome:)

This is the code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['wiel_submit']) && $_POST['wiel_submit'] == "Zoek")
{
    echo "\t\t\t\t\t<h2>".$stockselection."</h2>
\t\t\t\t\t<br />\n";
    $type = split("//", $_POST['wiel_type']);
?>
                    <ul class="wheels">
<?php
    $velgen = $wielclass->getWielenInformatie($_POST['wiel_merk'], $_POST['wiel_model'], $type[0], $_POST['wiel_inch']);
    $first = true;
    $vorigvelg = -1;
    $warningEmitted = false;
    foreach($velgen as $velg)
    {
        if($velg[11] === "IA" && !$warningEmitted && $velg[2] == "086" || $velg[2] == "251" || $velg[2] == "250" || $velg[2] == "249" || $velg[2] == "220" || $velg[2] == "217" || $velg[2] == "197" || $velg[2] == "182" || $velg[2] == "181" || $velg[2] == "180" || $velg[2] == "142" || $velg[2] == "141" || $velg[2] == "140" || $velg[2] == "139" || $velg[2] == "138" || $velg[2] == "137" || $velg[2] == "136" || $velg[2] == "135" || $velg[2] == "134" || $velg[2] == "132" || $velg[2] == "131" || $velg[2] == "130" || $velg[2] == "129" || $velg[2] == "128" || $velg[2] == "127" || $velg[2] == "126" || $velg[2] == "097" || $velg[2] == "096" || $velg[2] == "094"  || $velg[2] == "093" || $velg[2] == "092" || $velg[2] == "090" || $velg[2] == "122" || $velg[2] == "121" || $velg[2] == "120" || $velg[2] == "114" || $velg[2] == "112" || $velg[2] == "111" || $velg[2] == "109" || $velg[2] == "104" || $velg[2] == "103" || $velg[2] == "102" || $velg[2] == "099" || $velg[2] == "098" || $velg[2] == "123" || $velg[2] == "124" || $velg[2] == "125" || $velg[2] == "133" || $velg[2] == "071" || $velg[2] == "075" || $velg[2] == "084" || $velg[2] == "113" || $velg[2] == "108" || $velg[2] == "089" || $velg[2] == "073" || $velg[2] == "072" || $velg[2] == "101" || $velg[2] == "088")
        {

?>
                        <li><span class="title">Foto <?php echo $velg[2]; ?></span>
                            <a href="/portfolio/inter-action-<?php echo $velg[2]; ?>" class="preview" title="Fotonummer: <?php echo $velg[2]; ?>">
                                <img src="/wp-content/uploads/inter-action-<?php echo $velg[2]; ?>.jpg" alt="Fotonummer: <?php echo $velg[2]; ?>" class="wheelImg"/>
                            </a>
                            </span>
                        </li>
<?php
            $vorigvelg = $velg[2];
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Niets gevonden!";
            $warningEmitted = true;
        }

    }
?>
                    </ul>


<?php
}
?>
```

What I am trying to accomplish is that when "IA" is found and matches a certain number echo the list with images.

When "IA" is not found echo "Nothing Found" ONE time.

At this very moment he is showing "Nothing  Found" when "IA" is found and also when "IA" is not found. And because it is inside a foreach it is showing multiple times.

I tried almost everything but it is killing me atm...

Anyone has an idea how I can make this work?

Thnx

Comment: that if statement is strange, having AND and OR without additional brackets?

Comment: did you meant if($velg[11] === "IA" && !$warningEmitted && ($velg[2] == "086" || $velg[2] == "251"... ))?

Answer (score 0):

The if statement has to have all arguments in each ||

```
if($velg[11] === "IA" && !$warningEmitted && $velg[2] == "086" || $velg[11] === "IA" && !$warningEmitted && $velg[2] == "086" $velg[2] == "251" || $velg[11] === "IA" && !$warningEmitted && $velg[2] == "086" $velg[2] == "250" 
{
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is really not... ideal.

I think your problem is that `&&` binds closer than `||`, changing the condition of the `if`.

I would suggest changing it to:

```
$allowed = array(
    "086", "251", "250",
    "249", ...
);
if (
    ($velg[11] === "IA") &&
    (!$warningEmitted) &&
    (in_array($velg[2], $allowed))
)
{
   ... snip ...
}
else
{
   ... snip ...
}
```

which should fix your problem **and** make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Better use in array:

```
$values = array("086", "251", "250", "249", "220", "217", "197", "182", "181", "180", "142", "141", "140", "139", "138", "137", "136", "135", "134", "132", "131", "130", "129", "128", "127", "126", "097", "096", "094", "093", "092", "090", "122", "121", "120", "114", "112", "111", "109", "104", "103", "102", "099", "098", "123", "124", "125", "133", "071", "075", "084", "113", "108", "089", "073", "072", "101", "088");
if ($velg[11] === "IA" && !$warningEmitted && in_array($velg[2], $values)) {
    // statement
} else {
   $warningEmitted = true;
}
```